# getting customer details from the event: controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to capture the 'new customer registration details' from the following event:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost
```

I know that the  returns the customer object.

However, I need to capture the customer details post dispatch.

is there a way to get the customer object from the postdispatch event?

Comment: You can get it from session after post event dispatch.

Comment: you can use customer_register_success to get customer object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost>
    <observers>
        <customer_createpost>
            <class>yourmodelname/observer</class>
            <method>customerAccount</method>
        </customer_createpost>
    </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost>
```

Your observer function

```
<?php
class YourPackageName_YourModuleName_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerAccount(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($customer->getData()); exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data as below:

```
$observer->getControllerAction();
$observer->getData('controller_action');
var_dump($observer->getData());
exit;
```

Comment: this is the data it returns array (size=2)
  0 => string 'event' (length=5)
  1 => string 'controller_action' (length=17)

Comment: @theSeeker Please test Updated code.

Comment: i dont understand what that means

Comment: it will print all data of controller.